# how to run Phonegap app for ios audio file in background

Tags: ios, html, cordova, audio

I want to run my html5 audio player which is online streaming radio link to be played even if the device is locked (sleep mode) or the app is turned in background while opening another app. The player works very well when I start it as web app from Safari browser but now after I have built it for ios using Phonegap Build when the device is locked or the user switched between the apps in the device then the player stops. Is there any solution for this? Maybe a plugin?

Here is my web app in github: https://github.com/albpower/radio-pendimi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem using Background-audio ios Phonegap plugin. Here you can find more informations about plugin and usage from official Phonegap plugins directive. 
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1193